# How can I vary the width's of my li scroller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I'm ready to pick up this computer and throw it through the window. I have a horizontal ul thumbnail slider that opens up the thumbnails with lightbox. Each thumbnail opens a group of photos in lightbox. Both the slider and lightbox effects are working great, but every li is 1 of 3 different widths. So every li is either spaced wide apart or run into each other.

The li width is set to 100px with the CSS. If I leave the width undefined, the slider collapses and only shows the first couple thumbs.

I need this slider to work with 100px, 145px, and 175px widths. Any ideas? Obviously, I'm no expert.

**Here's the code for the slider:**

```
    <div id="slider1"> <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>
  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="som106" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="som106" title="My caption"></a><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="som106" title="My caption"></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/135_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/138_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/113_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/122_t.jpg"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/123_t.jpg"/></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="file:///S|/Design-Development/CUSTOMER DEVELOPMENT/SOLE OPTIONS/Web files (Johnny)/SO_site/flashIntro/img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption"><img src="img/thumbs/106_t.jpg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
      <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
#slider1 {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#slider1 .viewport {
    float: left;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slider1 .buttons {
    background: url("../images/buttons.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 10px 0 0;
    background-position: 0 -38px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    float: left;
    width: 39px;
    height: 37px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slider1 .next {
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
}
#slider1 .disable {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#slider1 .overview {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 240px;
left: 0 top: 0;
}
#slider1 .overview li {
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#slider1 .overviewMid li span {
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.overview li a {
    opacity: .7;
}
.overview li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Please Help! Thanks.**

Comment: look, your code is quite big and the question is unclear. I pasted your code to hopefully see an example in jsbin.com and get the issue you're facing. Nothing. Simply the code you posted is not understandable and **self-explanatory** to help you resolve your issue. Slice it down, create a demo otherwise I don't think you'll get answers for this one.

Comment: If you could get a demo snippet of your code workin on jsbin or jsfiddle, and provide the link to that, it would be much easier for others to help you.